# TensorFlow Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial: kernels seem to never learn anything

Tags: classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I'm following Google's TensorFlow Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/ePktssrn

The networks seems to get close to 100% accuracy after about training 1000 steps, but all of its kernels on the outermost layer remain completely unchanged.

Here's a visualization I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCklE.png
Each row represents one of 32 5x5 kernels defined by W_conv1; leftmost image in the row is initial state of the kernel, and each next image horizontally is how that kernel looks after 5 training steps.

As it can be clearly seen from the picture, kernels seem to be completely static.

I used the same code to draw kernels for a shallow network with convolutions, and they train very well - you can see shapes slowly forming out of noise. But on that particular example, kernels stay completely same.

Is this normal? Is this a flaw in google's example of deep CNN? Is this some mistake I made following the tutorial?

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I posted it. Images and link to code are all optional to understand what I mean: Google's Deep MNIST for Experts model has whole first row of convolution kernels completely unchanged during training, and I'm not sure it should be this way.